# A bounded sequence

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

I have a question please :

Let $f:[0,2\pi]\times \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a differential function satisfying :
 $\displaystyle k^2\leq \liminf_{|x|\rightarrow \infty} \frac{f(t,x)}{x}\leq \limsup_{|x|\rightarrow \infty}\frac{f(t,x)}{x} \leq (k+1)^2$

Let $(x_n)\subset H^1([0,2\pi],\mathbb{R})=\lbrace x\in L^2([0,2\pi],\mathbb{R}),x'\in L^2([0,2\pi],\mathbb{R}),x(0)=x(2\pi)\rbrace$

sucht that $\|x_n\|\rightarrow \infty$ when $n \rightarrow \infty$

Why : the sequence $\left(\displaystyle\frac{f(t,x_n)-k^2 x_n}{\|x_n\|}\right)$ is bounded ?

Is this answer given by :@TZakrevskiy true ?

> Well, we write
>
> $\limsup\limits_{|x|\to\infty} \frac{f(x)-k^2x}{x}\le 2k+1,$
>
> $\liminf\limits_{|x|\to\infty} \frac{f(x)-k^2x}{x}\ge 0.$
>
> Plus, $\frac{f(x)-k^2x}{x}$ and $\frac{f(x)-k^2x}{|x|}$ have the same
>   absolute value. Then, if $\limsup y_n\le C$ for a sequence $y_n$, then
>   $y_n$ has a finite upper bound, same goes for $\liminf$ and a finite
>   lower bound. Thus, for positive $x_n$ the sequence
>   $\frac{f(x_n)-k^2x_n}{|x_n|}$ is bounded.
>
> For $x_n<0$ we study
>
> $\limsup\limits_{|x|\to\infty} \frac{k^2x-f(x)}{-x}=\limsup\limits_{|x|\to\infty}
>  \frac{k^2x-f(x)}{|x|}\le 2k+1,$
>
> $\liminf\limits_{|x|\to\infty} \frac{k^2x-f(x)}{-x}=\liminf\limits_{|x|\to\infty}
>  \frac{k^2x-f(x)}{|x|}\ge 0,$ which gives us for negative $x_n$ the
>   sequence $\frac{k^2x-f(x)}{|x|}$ is bounded; and, clearly, so is the
>   sequence $-\frac{k^2x-f(x)}{|x|}$. This conludes the proof.

Please

Thank you .

Comment: What is $f(t,x_n)$? Do you mean the function $t \mapsto f(t, x_n(t))$?

Comment: I don't have the expretion of $f(t,x)$

Comment: @gerw can you help me please ?

Comment: I still do not know what $f(t,x_n)$ means. And in which space do you need the boundedness?

Comment: In the article they say : we see that $(f_1(t,x_n)/||x_n||)$ is bounded , we may assume that $\frac{f_1(t,x_n)}{||x_n||}\rightharpoonup \alpha(t) v$ weakly in $L^2([0,2\pi])$ for some function $\alpha(t)\in L^2([0,2\pi])$ satisfying $0\leq \alpha(t)\leq (k+1)^2-k^2$ for a.e $t\in [0,2\pi]$

Comment: What article are you referring to?

Comment: Multiple periodic solutions of ordinary differential equations with
double resonance

Comment: @TZakrevskiy have an idea please

Comment: @gerw have you an idea ? please

Comment: @Raindrop can you help me please ?

Comment: It looks like you've already answered your own question in the quoted part of your question. Assuming that the quoted part of your question is TZakrevskiy's answer, which specific part of TZakrevskiy's answer are you unsatisfied with? Try to spend some time thinking hard about TZakrevskiy's answer and whether it makes sense or not. I don't know analysis so I can't help you any further

Comment: i don't know if this unswer still right whene $x_n \in H^1$