# Question on $\liminf$ and $\limsup$

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, limsup-and-liminf

Let $f:[0,2\pi]\times \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a differential function satisfying :
 $\displaystyle k^2\leq \liminf_{|x|\rightarrow \infty} \frac{f(t,x)}{x}\leq \limsup_{|x|\rightarrow \infty}\frac{f(t,x)}{x} \leq (k+1)^2$

Let $(x_n)\subset H^1([0,2\pi],\mathbb{R})=\lbrace x\in L^2([0,2\pi],\mathbb{R}),x'\in L^2([0,2\pi],\mathbb{R}),x(0)=x(2\pi)\rbrace$

such that $\|x_n\|\rightarrow \infty$ when $n \rightarrow \infty$

Why : the sequence $(\displaystyle\frac{f(t,x_n)-k^2 x_n}{\|x_n\|})$ is bounded ?

This is an answer of a professor and I don't understand the line 6.
[image]

How to use :

$$\displaystyle k^2\leq \liminf_{|x|\rightarrow \infty} \frac{f(t,x)}{x}\leq \limsup_{|x|\rightarrow \infty}\frac{f(t,x)}{x} \leq (k+1)^2$$

to find :
$\displaystyle \| f(t,x_n)\|_{L^2}^2 =\int_0^{2\pi} f(t,x_n)^2 dt \leq  \max\lbrace (k+1)^4\int_0^{2\pi} |x_n|^2 dt , 2\pi M\rbrace$

where : $\displaystyle M=\sup_{(t,x)\in [0,2\pi]\times[-a,a]}|f(t,x)|$

Please help me ,

Thank you .

Comment: what is $\|x_n\|$?

Comment: it's a sequence from $H^1$ such that $x_n \rightarrow \infty$ when $n\rightarrow \infty$

Comment: I meant, what does this norm mean?

Comment: $||x_n||$ is norm on $H^1$ $||x||^2=\int_0^{2\pi} x'^2+x^2 dt$

Comment: Thanks, what is $f_1$ as in the very last row of professor's note?

Comment: $f_1(t,x)=f(t,x)-k^2 x$

Comment: Thanks, I've edited the answer - I think it shall clarify your confusion.

Answer (score 2):

After the details you've provided, the situation is quite different, but anyways the method is almost the same. The first trick is to notice that bounds on $\liminf$ and $\limsup$ tell you, that for any $\delta>0$ there exists $a(\delta)$ big enough such that
$$
  |x|\geq a(\delta)\implies |f(t,x)|\leq((k+1)^2+\delta)|x|.
$$
Let us denote $a:=a(1)$. Then
$$
  \|f(\cdot,x_n(\cdot))\|_2^2 = \int |f(t,x_n(t))|^2\mathrm dt = \int\limits_{\{t:|x_n|\leq a\}}|f(t,x_n(t))|^2\mathrm dt + \int\limits_{\{t:|x_n|\leq a\}}|f(t,x_n(t))|^2\mathrm dt
$$
$$
  \leq \int \sup_{t\in [0,2\pi],|x|\leq a}|f(t,x)|^2\mathrm dt + \int ((k+1)^2+\delta)^2|x_n(t)|^2\mathrm dt
$$
$$
  \leq 2\pi\sup_{t\in [0,2\pi],|x|\leq a}|f(t,x)|^2 + ((k+1)^2+\delta)^2\|x_n\|_2^2.
$$
where we always integrate over $t\in[0,2\pi]$ plus other possible constraints. This is a bit different from the bound in your notes, but still similar and works for showing that the sequence is bounded as well. Please tell me, whether it something is still unclear to you.

Another point is that you shall not rely precisely upon the notes of your professor, that often may have just the general idea rather than the perfectly precise sequence of statements, especially when it comes to the asymptotic results.

Comment: how we find the $a$ ? please

Comment: i don't understand how to use $\displaystyle k^2\leq \liminf_{|x|\rightarrow \infty} \frac{f(t,x)}{x}\leq \limsup_{|x|\rightarrow \infty}\frac{f(t,x)}{x} \leq (k+1)^2$

Comment: @Vrouvrou: we need more details from your book here: could you please answer my questions?

Comment: look here :http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/419435/a-bounded-sequence

Comment: @Vrouvrou: what is $a$ in your case then? Also, your post in its current shape is not informative at all. Now it appears that $x$ is a function of $t$ and $x_n$ is a particular sequence of such functions. All this information *has* to be mentioned in the original post, you shall not expect people looking for all of your posts in order to guess what you mean.

Comment: ok i'm sorry ! i will edited my question

Comment: i edited my question if you can help me please i am despairing

Comment: hello; why we have exactly this :$|x|\geq a(\delta)\implies |f(t,x)|\leq((k+1)^2+\delta)|x|$ and where is the maximum ? please thank you

Comment: @Vrouvrou: that's how $a(\delta)$ is chosen. The existence of it follows from the limsup, that is if you suppose that for some delta such a does not exist, the limsup has to be different. Which maximum are you talking about?

Comment: $\displaystyle \| f(t,x_n)\|_{L^2}^2 =\int_0^{2\pi} f(t,x_n)^2 dt \leq  \max\lbrace (k+1)^4\int_0^{2\pi} |x_n|^2 dt , 2\pi M\rbrace$

Comment: @Vrouvrou: I told you, I'm not sure whether one can obtain that bound - I obtained a different equivalent one, which I wrote in my answer: I used a sum, not a maximum.